# Filter Nulls when converting pandas dataframe to dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe.

```
 technologies = [
 ("Spark", 22000,'30days',1000.0, 'Scala'),
         ("PySpark",25000,'50days',2300.0, 'Python'),
 ("Hadoop",23000,'55days',np.nan,np.nan)
 ]
 df = pd.DataFrame(technologies,columns = ['Courses','Fee','Duration','Discount', 'Language'])
 print(df)

   Courses    Fee Duration  Discount Language
0    Spark  22000   30days    1000.0    Scala
1  PySpark  25000   50days    2300.0   Python
2   Hadoop  23000   55days       NaN      NaN
```

I am interested to convert every row into a dict.

```
def convert_to_dict(row) -> dict:
    result = dict(row)
    final_result = {k:v for k, v in result.items() if v is not np.nan}
    print(final_result)
```

So i use the above function and this trick

```
df.apply(lambda row: convert_to_dict(row), axis=1)
```

But the result i get is weird.

```
{'Courses': 'Spark', 'Fee': 22000, 'Duration': '30days', 'Discount': 1000.0, 'Language': 'Scala'}
{'Courses': 'PySpark', 'Fee': 25000, 'Duration': '50days', 'Discount': 2300.0, 'Language': 'Python'}
{'Courses': 'Hadoop', 'Fee': 23000, 'Duration': '55days', 'Discount': nan}
```

The last row had Language and Discount both as Nan.

And i expected that both should have been filtered out but i see only Language is filtered out.

How do i filter out all columns from the final result which are nan to filter out please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) for filtering missing values:

```
final_result = {k:v for k, v in result.items() if pd.notna(v)}
```

---

```
final_result = [{k:v for k, v in result.items() if pd.notna(v)} 
                for result in df.to_dict('records')]
print(final_result)
[{'Courses': 'Spark', 'Fee': 22000, 'Duration': '30days', 'Discount': 1000.0, 'Language': 'Scala'}, 
 {'Courses': 'PySpark', 'Fee': 25000, 'Duration': '50days', 'Discount': 2300.0, 'Language': 'Python'}, 
 {'Courses': 'Hadoop', 'Fee': 23000, 'Duration': '55days'}]
```

Comment: I wonder, why? it was anyway `np.Nan` why filtering on `np.Nan` did not work?

Comment: Hi Jezrael Thanks again for comming to my rescue indeed your solution rocks!!!

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - Hard question, maybe because NaN is some kind of `special` number (but should be string also)

Comment: @jezrael, second part of your answer is my answer ;)

Comment: @I'mahdi - Not understand, your first answer https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73046575/revisions was incorrect, not removed missing values. I extend my solution in 3 minutes after my first post to this solution and was surprises after 5 minutes see same answer in your question. So only ask if see it was already posted.

Comment: @jezrael, I can't prove my saying because you edit under 5 min and other can not see. I delete my answer to correct this, but after editing you add my answer. Because at first I think OP want to get all `nan` but after reading I understand filter all `nan` then edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.to_dict('records')` and filter `nan` with [`pandas.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
>>> [{k:v for k,v in dct.items() if pd.notna(v)} for dct in df.to_dict('records')]
[{'Courses': 'Spark',
  'Fee': 22000,
  'Duration': '30days',
  'Discount': 1000.0,
  'Language': 'Scala'},
 {'Courses': 'PySpark',
  'Fee': 25000,
  'Duration': '50days',
  'Discount': 2300.0,
  'Language': 'Python'},
 {'Courses': 'Hadoop', 'Fee': 23000, 'Duration': '55days'}]
```

Comment: It is same answer like mine.

Comment: @jezrael, No I see your answer, you add my answer after editing but under 5 min and other users can't see

Comment: @jezrael, why do you add second part of your answer.

Comment: Because apply here is not necessary?

Comment: @jezrael, do I use `apply`?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.apply(lambda ss:ss.loc[ss.notna()].to_dict(),axis=1).map(print)
```

out：

```
{'Courses': 'Spark', 'Fee': 22000, 'Duration': '30days', 'Discount': 1000.0, 'Language': 'Scala'}
{'Courses': 'PySpark', 'Fee': 25000, 'Duration': '50days', 'Discount': 2300.0, 'Language': 'Python'}
{'Courses': 'Hadoop', 'Fee': 23000, 'Duration': '55days'}
```